# Error Code: 1292 - Truncated Incorrect DOUBLE value: '-'

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1292

```
SET @newNum = IF(
    RIGHT("-600.00",1) REGEXP '^[-]' = '-',
    REPLACE("-600.00",",",""),
    -1*REPLACE(REPLACE("-600.00",",",""),"-","")
);
```

I keep getting a truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '-' when executing this line, anyone know what is causing this ?

Comment: `RIGHT("-600.00",1) REGEXP '^[-]' = '-'` doesn't make sense logically (although syntactically MySQL will parse this as something).  Another example why showing sample data and desired results is more useful than code that doesn't work.

Comment: Basically if someone puts "600.00-" or "-600.00" it will output "-600".

Comment: . . That's nice.  What do you want the code to do?  What does the data look like?  Generally, a conditional expression with two comparisons (in this case `regexp` and `=`) doesn't make sense.

Comment: The code needs to format numbers if they are given in an incorrect format (ex: "600.00- --> "-600.00"). I don't know what you mean by what the data looks like ? What would you suggest instead of  `regexp` and `=`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`REGEXP` returns 1 or 0 depending on whether there is a match or not. Comparing the result with `-` is incorrect, you can do this instead:

```
DECLARE @oldNum VARCHAR(10);
DECLARE @newNum VARCHAR(10);
SET @oldNum = '600.00-';
SET @newNum = IF(
    RIGHT(@oldNum, 1) = '-',
    CONCAT('-', REPLACE(REPLACE(@oldNum, ',', ''), '-', '')),
                        REPLACE(@oldNum, ',', '')
);
SELECT @oldNum, @newNum
```